# Mysql join two tables and limit by and order one table

Tags: mysql, sql

i am only starting to play with MySQL and i seem to have been stumped by one problem.

I have 2 tables that I have left joined them with the part of working but it's not enough. I want them be order by id in one table by top and down this table messages

Example

table chat

```
id
1
2
3
```

table messages

```
chat_id
1
2
3

SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM `messages` ) AS m LEFT JOIN
     chat as c
     ON m.chat_id = c.id
WHERE c.one ='$user_id' OR c.two = '$user_id' 
GROUP BY c.id, m.chat_id  
ORDER BY m.dates DESC  
LIMIT 8
```

Comment: What do you need from the query? list of all messages in a chat ordered by id?

Comment: @JoeyPinto yes dear when user send new message this message have been topic

Comment: update you question add a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: why are you grouping by c.id and m.chat_id? they are the same

Comment: @scaisEdge see link image https://image.ibb.co/is2fNv/msmsms.png like it

Comment: @inarilo i want create recent message in messages show one message and who user send  messages like messenger facebook :/

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get a list of chats with the most recent message from each chat?

If so, your best bet is to add a column to the chat table and include a 'latest_message_id' so you can query like this:

`SELECT * FROM chat LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.id = chat.latest_message_id`

Otherwise you will need to run a really big subquery which will waste lots of CPU and memory

Comment: Dab yes i want show one text message and list user from by messages